# "could not find function" only when in the R debugger

Tags: r, debugging

I've been running into this from time to time but for the first time I have simple reproducible example. The fact that the example involves lubridate is, I believe, coincidental. In R --vanilla session

```
library(lubridate)
ymd("2001-02-02")
# [1] "2001-02-02 UTC"
# so far so good
debug(ymd)
ymd("2001-02-02")
# debugging in: ymd("2001-02-02")
# Error in ymd("2001-02-02") : could not find function ".parse_xxx"
```

There is nothing wrong with ymd, I was trying to learn some things. But when you are actually debugging and this happens, it's very annoying. Debugger bug or am I missing something?

Version info

```
    > R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2014                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        66913                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
nickname       Pumpkin Helmet
```

And session infor per @Joshua Urlich comment

```
  > sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.3.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4  memoise_0.2.1 plyr_1.8.1    Rcpp_0.11.3   stringr_0.6.2
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your `sessionInfo`?

Comment: If you run `sessionInfo()` it will also give info on what packages you have loaded and what versions they are.

Comment: FWIW, I also see this behavior in 3.1.2 on OS X.

Comment: `.parse_xxx` is an unexported `lubridate` function. So, perhaps `debug` just isn't built to be run on functions already in packages? At least, not if they're calling hidden functions.

Comment: Reproducible on `R v3.1.3`, OS X v10.10.2. `debug(lubridate:::.parse_xxx)` works fine.. so seems like a bug to me..

Comment: It's going to hinge on `ymd` consisting of only that single call to an un-exported function, since un-exported functions don't seem to cause a problem in other cases for me. Must be something about how the initial evaluation frame is created...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it might have to do with the functions not being defined using `{}`.  The current implementation is:

```
ymd <- function(..., quiet = FALSE, tz = "UTC", locale = Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"),  truncated = 0)
  .parse_xxx(..., orders = "ymd", quiet = quiet, tz = tz, locale = locale,  truncated = truncated)
```

Your `debug` attempt works if I unpack the source, and change the implementation to:

```
ymd <- function(..., quiet = FALSE, tz = "UTC", locale = Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"),  truncated = 0)
{  .parse_xxx(..., orders = "ymd", quiet = quiet, tz = tz, locale = locale,  truncated = truncated)}
```

I was able to replicate the issue before making the above change. After making it, I get:

```
> require(lubridate); debug(ymd); ymd("2015-01-01")
Loading required package: lubridate
debugging in: ymd("2015-01-01")
debug: {
    .parse_xxx(..., orders = "ymd", quiet = quiet, tz = tz, locale = locale, 
        truncated = truncated)
}
Browse[2]> 
debug: .parse_xxx(..., orders = "ymd", quiet = quiet, tz = tz, locale = locale, 
    truncated = truncated)
Browse[2]> 
exiting from: ymd("2015-01-01")
[1] "2015-01-01 UTC"
```

Comment: I'm amazed by how quickly you cloned `lubridate`, edited, installed, and answered this question.

Comment: And  how did  you think of that?? Could be related to an issue with the covr package which was resolved by the same code transformation. My question was bug or my mistake and that has been answered in the comments. BrodieG offered a workaround Joshua  narrowed down the problem a couple of orders of magnitude. Lots of credit and only one answer to accept.

Comment: @piccolbo: it was a hunch. My original hypothesis was that the function definition was `ymd <- .parse_xxx`. When I saw that wasn't the definition, I thought it might help to keep the source and/or turn off byte compilation (via passing `--with-keep.source` and/or `--no-byte-compile` to `R CMD INSTALL`, respectively). When neither of those worked, I thought, "Not using curly braces when creating a function isn't particularly 'standard', so let's try adding them...".

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution or explanation but a potential work around:

```
trace(ymd, browser)
```

Then:

```
> ymd("2001-02-02")
Tracing ymd("2001-02-02") on entry 
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
Browse[1]> n
debug: .parse_xxx(..., orders = "ymd", quiet = quiet, tz = tz, locale = locale, 
    truncated = truncated)
Browse[2]>
```

I am able to recreate your error on Win7 R3.1.2 / RStudio.  I was hoping to recreate the problem with `trace` to try to poke around, but any `trace` of the function destroys the problem...